# TBalloonHint alignment in Delphi 11.2

Tags: delphi, hint, delphi-11-alexandria

In my app, I use the `TBalloonhint` component because it is better than the component's hint presenter, but I have a little problem.

When the control is close to the right border of the screen, the entire tooltip is not visible (unless the screen continues to a second screen).

Is there a way to move the hint to the left?